# Use Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality to prove statement

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that (acos(θ)+bsin(θ))$^2$ $\leq$
a$^2$ +b$^2$ for all a,b,θ ∈ $\mathbb{R}$

What I was trying to do was to take the smaller of either a or b and prove that (acos(θ)+bsin(θ))$^2$ $\leq$ a$^2$ if a were smaller than b. Then I created two vectors $\vec{v}$, $\vec{u}\in \mathbb{R^n}$ where ||$\vec{v}$||=a and ||$\vec{u}$|| = b and tried to use the reverse of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but that didn't work because I wasn't sure if the new expression I got was $\leq$(acos(θ)+bsin(θ))$^2$

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=(a,b)$ and $v=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. The left hand side is $|u\cdot v|^2$ and the right hand side is $|u|^2|v|^2$. Apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
(a\cos \theta + b\sin \theta)^{2} \leq (a^{2}+b^{2})(\cos^{2}\theta + \sin^{2}\theta) = a^{2} + b^{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $u=(a,b)$ and $v=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$. Then, $$||u||^2=a^2+b^2, \quad ||v||^2=\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1, \quad \langle u,v\rangle=a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta).$$

Hence, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $$|\langle u,v\rangle|^2 \leq ||u||\cdot||v|| \implies (a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta))^2 \leq a^2+b^2$$